# JWT Token could not be verifed before

Tags: jwt

I am currently using JWT since the past month and I had no issues. But since yesterday, I am experiencing this error as per below

**com.auth0.jwt.exceptions.InvalidClaimException: The Token can't be used before.**..

I understand there is a timestamp when generating the token and the token cannot 
 be verified before that. The token is being verified on another server. But all this time, it was fine. Can someone advise?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps try viewing your JWT token using https://jwt.io/ - can you ascertain whether it has expired? Take the exp value (likely epoch) and convert - https://www.epochconverter.com/

You have added very little info in the question to offer any further details. You could try (re-) authenticating with the IDP that issued you the JWT token last time, and check whether that resolves your issue too.

Based on your last comment, do the servers have any clock skew?

Comment: I don't think it is about expiration of the token. Token was generated on a server at 10:34:01. And then it was vefiried on another server lets say at 10:33:09. I thnk that is the problem

Comment: Do the servers have any clock skew?

Comment: Hello, I could not solve it. It happened a second time in 3 months. I guess it should be something with the servers.

Comment: Well, i have advised as you requested, so please acknowledge the answer, either by upvoting or marking as correct. Thank you :)

Comment: @arcseldon If the OP failed to fix the problem, how is this possibly a correct answer?

Comment: Hey @DanRayson - are you having a similar problem? Feel free to leave a comment if so, and I'll try to answer your situation. Did you try all the above? No need to downvote.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using auth0-spring-security-api then you can customize leeway as follow:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Value(value = "${auth0.audience}")
private String apiAudience;

@Value(value = "${auth0.issuer}")
private String issuer;

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {      
    final JwkProvider jwkProvider = new JwkProviderBuilder(issuer).build();
    JwtAuthenticationProvider jwtAuthenticationProvider = new JwtAuthenticationProvider(jwkProvider, issuer,
            apiAudience);
    jwtAuthenticationProvider.withJwtVerifierLeeway(3);

    JwtWebSecurityConfigurer.forRS256(apiAudience, issuer, jwtAuthenticationProvider).configure(http)
            .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**").authenticated();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all have a look at your AUTH provider tenant settings. If the *Login Session Management -> Inactivity timeout* is set to too low, try increasing it and see if the error is happening.

OR

try: https://auth0.com/docs/libraries/auth0js/v8